# Reactjs doesn't render a div tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, laravel, jsx

I'm using reactjs in a laravel 8 project, when I try to render this component:

```
    <main className="main-container">
{/* new collection directory */}
<section id="content-block" className="slider_area">
    <div className="container">
        <div className="content-push">
            <div className="row">

                <div className="col-md-3 col-md-push-9">
                    <div className="sidebar-navigation">
                        <div className="title">Product Categories<i className="fa fa-angle-down"> </i>
                        </div>
                        <div className="list">
                            <a className="entry" href="#"> <span> <i className="fa fa-angle-right"> </i>Evening dresses</span> </a>
                            <a className="entry" href="#"> <span> <i className="fa fa-angle-right"> </i>Jackets and coats</span> </a>
                            <a className="entry" href="#"> <span> <i className="fa fa-angle-right"> </i>Tops and Sweatshirts</span> </a>
                            <a className="entry" href="#"> <span> <i className="fa fa-angle-right"> </i>Blouses and shirts</span> </a>
                            <a className="entry" href="#"> <span> <i className="fa fa-angle-right"> </i>Trousers and Shorts</span> </a>
                            <a className="entry" href="#"> <span> <i className="fa fa-angle-right"> </i>Evening dresses</span> </a>
                            <a className="entry" href="#"> <span> <i className="fa fa-angle-right"> </i>Jackets and coats</span> </a>
                            <a className="entry" href="#"> <span> <i className="fa fa-angle-right"> </i>Tops and Sweatshirts</span> </a>
                            <a className="entry" href="#"> <span> <i className="fa fa-angle-right"> </i>Blouses and shirts</span> </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="clear"> </div>
                </div>

                <div className="col-md-9 col-md-pull-3">

                    <div className="header_slider">
                        <article className="boss_slider">
                            <div className="tp-banner-container">
                                <div className="tp-banner tp-banner0">
                                    <ul>
                                        {/* SLIDE  */}
                                        <li data-link="#" data-target="_self" data-transition="flyin"
                                            data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500"
                                            data-saveperformance="on">
                                            {/* MAIN IMAGE */} <img src="img/dummy.png" alt="slidebg1"
                                                                    data-lazyload="img/slide/slider1.png"
                                                                    data-bgposition="left center"
                                                                    data-kenburns="off"
                                                                    data-duration="14000"
                                                                    data-ease="Linear.easeNone"
                                                                    data-bgpositionend="right center"/>
                                            {/* LAYER NR. 1 */}
                                            <div
                                                    className="tp-caption very_big_white randomrotate customout rs-parallaxlevel-0"
                                                    data-x="270" data-y="140"
                                                    data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                                                    data-speed="300" data-start="500" data-end="4800"
                                                    data-endspeed="300" data-easing="easeInOutBack"
                                                    data-endeasing="easeOutBack" data-elementdelay="0.1"
                                                    data-endelementdelay="0.1" style="z-index: 2;"> Trendy
                                            </div>
                                            {/* LAYER NR. 2 */}
                                            <div
                                                    className="tp-caption very_large_white_text randomrotate customout rs-parallaxlevel-0"
                                                    data-x="270" data-y="250"
                                                    data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                                                    data-speed="300" data-start="800" data-end="4800"
                                                    data-endspeed="300" data-easing="easeInOutBack"
                                                    data-endeasing="easeOutBack" data-elementdelay="0.1"
                                                    data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                                                    style="z-index: 2;"> selection
                                            </div>
                                            {/* LAYER NR. 3 */}
                                            <div
                                                    className="tp-caption large_white_text randomrotate customout rs-parallaxlevel-0"
                                                    data-x="355" data-y="363"
                                                    data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                                                    data-speed="300" data-start="1200" data-end="4800"
                                                    data-endspeed="300" data-easing="easeInOutBack"
                                                    data-endeasing="easeOutBack" data-elementdelay="0.1"
                                                    data-endelementdelay="0.1" style="z-index: 2;"> SHOP NOW
                                            </div>

                                        </li>
                                        <li data-link="#" data-target="_self"
                                            data-transition="3dcurtain-horizontal" data-slotamount="7"
                                            data-masterspeed="500" data-saveperformance="on">
                                            {/* MAIN IMAGE */} <img src="img/dummy.png" alt="slidebg1"
                                                                    data-lazyload="img/slide/slider2.png"
                                                                    data-bgposition="left center"
                                                                    data-kenburns="off"
                                                                    data-duration="14000"
                                                                    data-ease="Linear.easeNone"
                                                                    data-bgpositionend="right center"/>
                                            {/* LAYER NR. 1 */}
                                            <div
                                                    className="tp-caption very_big_white fade customout rs-parallaxlevel-0"
                                                    data-x="270" data-y="140"
                                                    data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                                                    data-speed="300" data-start="500" data-end="4800"
                                                    data-endspeed="300" data-easing="easeOutBack"
                                                    data-endeasing="easeOutBack" data-elementdelay="0.1"
                                                    data-endelementdelay="0.1" style="z-index: 2;"> Trendy
                                            </div>
                                            {/* LAYER NR. 2 */}
                                            <div
                                                    className="tp-caption very_large_white_text fade customout rs-parallaxlevel-0"
                                                    data-x="270" data-y="250"
                                                    data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                                                    data-speed="300" data-start="800" data-end="4800"
                                                    data-endspeed="300" data-easing="easeOutBack"
                                                    data-endeasing="easeOutBack" data-elementdelay="0.1"
                                                    data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                                                    style="z-index: 2;"> selection
                                            </div>
                                            {/* LAYER NR. 3 */}
                                            <div
                                                    className="tp-caption large_white_text fade customout rs-parallaxlevel-0"
                                                    data-x="355" data-y="363"
                                                    data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                                                    data-speed="300" data-start="1200" data-end="4800"
                                                    data-endspeed="300" data-easing="easeOutBack"
                                                    data-endeasing="easeOutBack" data-elementdelay="0.1"
                                                    data-endelementdelay="0.1" style="z-index: 2;"> SHOP NOW
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li data-transition="boxslide" data-slotamount="7"
                                            data-masterspeed="500" data-saveperformance="on">
                                            {/* MAIN IMAGE */} <img src="img/dummy.png" alt="slidebg1"
                                                                    data-lazyload="img/slide/slide_3.jpg"
                                                                    data-bgposition="left center"
                                                                    data-kenburns="off"
                                                                    data-duration="14000"
                                                                    data-ease="Linear.easeNone"
                                                                    data-bgpositionend="right center"/>
                                            {/* LAYER NR. 1 */}
                                            <div
                                                    className="tp-caption large_white_text skewfromleftshort customout rs-parallaxlevel-0"
                                                    data-x="355" data-y="363"
                                                    data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                                                    data-speed="300" data-start="1200" data-end="4800"
                                                    data-endspeed="300" data-easing="easeOutBack"
                                                    data-endeasing="easeOutBack" data-elementdelay="0.1"
                                                    data-endelementdelay="0.1" style="z-index: 2;"> SHOP NOW
                                            </div>
                                            {/* LAYER NR. 2 */}
                                            <div
                                                    className="tp-caption very_large_white_text skewfromleftshort customout rs-parallaxlevel-0"
                                                    data-x="270" data-y="250"
                                                    data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                                                    data-speed="300" data-start="800" data-end="4800"
                                                    data-endspeed="300" data-easing="easeOutBack"
                                                    data-endeasing="easeOutBack" data-elementdelay="0.1"
                                                    data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                                                    style="z-index: 2;"> selection
                                            </div>
                                            {/* LAYER NR. 3 */}
                                            <div
                                                    className="tp-caption very_big_white skewfromleftshort customout rs-parallaxlevel-0"
                                                    data-x="270" data-y="140"
                                                    data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                                                    data-speed="300" data-start="500" data-end="4800"
                                                    data-endspeed="300" data-easing="easeOutBack"
                                                    data-endeasing="easeOutBack" data-elementdelay="0.1"
                                                    data-endelementdelay="0.1" style="z-index: 2;"> Trendy
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div className="slideshow_control"> </div>
                                </div>
                                {/* /.tp-banner */}
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                    {/* /.header_slider */}

                    <div className="clear"> </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{/* end new collection directory */}




<div className="bt-block-home-parallax" style="background-image: url('img/block_parallax.jpg');">
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <div className="lookbook-product">
                    <h2> <a href="#" title="">Collection 2016 </a> </h2>
                    <ul className="simple-cat-style">
                        <li> <a href="#" title="">Dresses</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#" title="">Coats & Jackets</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#" title="">Jeans</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="#" title="">read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</main>
```

When I render it, it returns a blank page, I have done some troubleshooting and noticed that the problem occurs only with this component, although they are other component that have same tags structure that works fine, but when I change the div tag to fragment for example it work, so my question is is there something wrong with the div tags in my code , and thanks in advance.
More Details:
The file containing this code is in a screens directory, in screen/index.js file I wrote the following code:

```
     import React,{Fragment} from 'react';
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";

class Index extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return(
            <Fragment>
            <Header/>
            {this.props.children}
            <Footer/>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default Index;
```

And in js/index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Index from "./screens/index";
import Home from "./screens/Home";
import NotFound from "./screens/NotFound";
import Shop from "./screens/Shop";
import Signin from "./screens/Signin";
import Signup from "./screens/Signup";
import Contact from "./screens/Contact";
import About from "./screens/About";
import Cart from "./screens/Cart";
import Wishlist from "./screens/Wihslist";
import Checkout from "./screens/Checkout";

class  App extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
                <Index>
                    <Router>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/shop" component={Shop} />
                        <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
                        ...
                    </Router>
                </Index>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The element in my html file with the app id is actually the body tag, rendering in other tag doesn't solve the problem, and I don't think that there is a problem with header and footer component either since they work with other screens (component) just fine.

Comment: When you open the browser's developer console, are there any errors?

Comment: it says nothing in the console.

Comment: Can you post the whole component and not just the JSX ? I cannot see anything wrong, maybe it is your component's logic.

Comment: Can you add `index.html/php`? Does it contains element with `app` id? Does it include `js/index.js` script?

Comment: its a laravel project so it does include the app.js script where index.js is imported, I guess this is not the problem since the other component work, this problem happen only with the home component.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem, it is in the style attribute that only div tags have, it's written in the html style like:

```
<div style="z-index: 2">...</div>
```

Instead of the acceptable way with reactjs which is:

```
<div style={{zIndex: '2'}}>...</div>
```